# Multiple files uploading in asp.netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc, iformfile

I want to save multiple images against one object in database and want to show these images in an  tag[image]

as mentioned in pic below i am little bit confuse how to manage it in database 
against one object

that's means if  i have  5 images against an object watch then how save 5 different paths in database

2nd confusion is that how to get these images against single click in asp.net core because file uploading in mvc-6 is little bit different from mvc-5

Comment: what you  have tried so  far we need the code

Comment: You could create a separate table for the images which have a foreign key to products table.

Comment: ok and i try to upload a single file and save it to database and search for multiple files but failed

Comment: @ganeshran but how get these files from html in web forms i have an option of "runat=server", and don't know how in asp.net core

Comment: `runat` is a Web Form-ism. It has nothing to do with MVC, any version.

Comment: @ChrisPratt have you any solution how to get multiple files